# Getting index of an item in List of non primitive type

Tags: java, list

Here is my class Info

```
public class Info {
    public String imei;
    public Integer delta;
}
```

and my

```
List<Info> Records;
```

Is there a simple way to get the index of an Info, where for example imei is 356307044597945, or I must go through the list, comparing all the elements?

Comment: You have to go through the list. If you don't want to, use a Map.

Comment: You can override the equals and hashCode method of Info class and then use indexOf() method of list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement the equals/hashCode methods:

```
public class Info {

    public String imei;
    public Integer delta;

    public Info(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Info && obj.imei.equals(imei);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { imei });
    }

}
```

Then:

```
int index = records.indexOf(new Info("356307044597945"));
```

Not sure if it's a good practice though, waiting for up or down votes ;)

Comment: I'm using this class for only getting some info from a json and displaying, so in my case I think it's good practice)

Comment: Related to your equals implementation, two objects having the same hash code are [NOT necessarily equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443136/are-two-java-objects-with-same-hashcodes-not-necessarily-equal)

Comment: @Daniel, just want to clarify, in my case it will still work because imei is unique, won't it?

Comment: @Carmine What Daniel meant is that my equals implementation were wrong, since two objects that have the same hashCode are not necessarily equal (see [hash collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science))). I edited my answer anyway, it's now safe so you can use it ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is no method in `List` interface to find the objects on the basis of an object attribute. So you need to iterate through your List.

Better use `Map` to provide a key value pair mappings for your need. `Map` is definitely a better choice because using Map you will be able to get the desired object with O(1) complexity instead of O(n) when compared to iteration over List.

You may use `imei` as the key for your map and corresponding `Info` object as the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an index,maintain a `Map` of your `Info` Object and with String as a Key, which is your `imei` (assuming that is Unique.).

Otherwise there is no way to directly get it from list without looking (looping) into List.